# How can I use 'xx time ago' as date format?

Tags: nodes, 8, datetime

How can I use 'xx time ago' for date format in Drupal 8 nodes ?

I want to replace "xx time ago" with {{ date }} in node.

In Drupal 7 it worked with this code :

```
<?php
 print format_interval(time()-$node->created);
?>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your objective is? Where do you want to display "time ago"? Which fields do you want to display "time ago"? Have you done any work on this?

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean?  Just just pick that display format under Manage Display, and then pick your options.

Comment: I want replace "xx time ago" with {{ date }} in node

Comment: Please update the question with extra details.

Comment: So basically, http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/95376/trying-to-render-a-custom-date-format-with-twig?rq=1

Comment: More specifically, this answer, http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/194883/42650, in the question I posted previously, is what you're looking for. You can find more information about Twig, date function, and string concatenation on other sites. Or use views.

Comment: @mradcliffe, timeago is what the OP needs here.  There's a twig filter for that but it does not seem to work `{{ date|time_diff }}`. The post you are linking to does not touch upon timeago.

Comment: I'm sure that a developer can come up with a solution with the resources provided.

Comment: The `time_diff` Twig function is provided by The Date Extension, which I don't think is provided by core (haven't looked for an issue, but may be an interesting feature request). @Bahman, we still need to know what you are trying to print out from the node in your Twig, field(s) or updated/created in timeago format?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two ways to tackle this.

One is to just use the field formatters.  If you have a DateTime field, just goto **Manage Display**, and change the **Format** to **Time ago**.  Then click the gear, and pick some options.  These are cache aware that will bubble up through the page, but you may end up with short cache lifetimes in some situations.

The other is to use a `template_preprocess_node()`.  This is preferable when you have a timestamp that isn't a field.  Then you use the date formatter service to render out the timestamp in timeago format.  It is preferable to use the formatDiff() versions rather than formatInterval() (while not formally deprecated, it is discouraged).

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  /** @var \Drupal\Core\Datetime\DateFormatterInterface $formatter */
  $date_formatter = \Drupal::service('date.formatter');
  $request_time = \Drupal::time()->getRequestTime();
  $variables['foo'] = $date_formatter->formatDiff($request_time - 12345, $request_time, [
    'granularity' => 3,
    'return_as_object' => TRUE,
  ])->toRenderable();
}
```

When you specify `'return_as_object' => TRUE` with the formatDiff() functions, a `FormattedDateDiff` object gets returned, which contains the formatted string as well as a mostly accurate `[#cache]['max-age']` entry in a render array to make this work with Drupal 8's new caching system.  Then you can just use `{{ foo }}` in your Twig template; the render engine will do the right thing with the render array instead of a plain string.

Also read the docs on `DateFormatterInterface` for the `formatTimeDiffSince()` and `formatTimeDiffUntil()` variants, and for the `$options you can pass in`.

Answer (score 3):

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Datetime%21DateFormatter.php/function/DateFormatter%3A%3AformatTimeDiffSince/8.2.x

$this->date->formatTimeDiffSince($time_stamp);

or

\Drupal::service('date.formatter')->formatTimeDiffSince($time_stamp);

Comment: works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach is to prepare it in ỳourtheme_preprocess_node() and then just print it in the twig template.

However, with D8's render caching, trying to do a time ago output on the server side can not work, unless you disable caching. It will be calculated on the first request and then never change again.

Instead, you want to send the time in an easy to parse markup, and then use JS to display it as a time ago format. See how d.o does that for comment dates: https://www.drupal.org/node/2704717 (it also includes functionality to switch between relative and absolute dates with a double click).

Comment: Well, https://www.drupal.org/node/2500525 landed, so timeago on anything using the formatters should work, which will set some reasonable TTLs on the elements.  You can also just set the max-age to 0 in #cache, and let that prevent caching for you, or pick your own lifetime.

Comment: Looks like there is a module for this now, https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_extensions, see `Date: Adds a filter for rendering the difference between dates.` and then the documentation at http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/date.html, thus `{{ date|time_diff }}`

Comment: @DannyEnglander Yeah, that is from one of the theme system maintainers.  Personally, I would opt for using the Drupal methods to take into account cache contexts, timezone, translation, etc.

Answer (score 2):

**Twig has a native Date extension that provides a "Time Ago" filter**

See http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/date.html

**|time_diff** is the one you want. The problem is Drupal doesn't include this extension by default.

So to get this in your twig templates do the following

- Install Twig Extensions Drupal Module (Be sure to follow the instructions) - https://www.drupal.org/project
- In Terminal in your Drupal Site

  - $ composer require twig/extensions
  - (be patient ... it took a while)
- Enable Module
- Use the Filter in your Twig templates

  {{ field_my_date|time_diff }}

Renders like "10 MONTHS AGO"

Comment: There isn't much documentation, so some experimentation may be in order. For me, I got it working with {{ node.getCreatedTime|time_diff }} . It may take some rooting through your theme templates to find what fields are available.

Comment: this isnt a Drupal module (or it would come from drupal/{project} in composer; so what does "enable module" mean?

Comment: This has to be added as a service. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311197/twig-time-ago-format

Answer (score 0):

Here is Answer,

in your .theme file add below code

```
function themename_preprocess_comment(&$variables) {

  $date = $variables['comment']->getCreatedTime();
  $variables['created'] = \Drupal::service('date.formatter')->formatInterval(REQUEST_TIME - $date);
  $variables['submitted'] = t('@author', array('@author' => $variables['author'], '!datetime' => '<span class="comments-ago ">' . $variables['created'] . ' ago </span>'));

}
```

and render in your `comment.html.twig` file below code

```
{{ created }} {{ 'ago'|t }}
```

hope it will helpfull thank you...