# How can I use xx time ago in Drupal 8 comments?

Tags: 8, datetime, comments

I use Drupal 8 and want the date of comments just show "***xx time ago***".

I added this code to `mytheme.theme`, but it does not work:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_comment(&$variables) { 
/** @var \Drupal\Core\Datetime\DateFormatterInterface $formatter */
$date_formatter = \Drupal::service('date.formatter');

$variables['foo'] = $date_formatter->formatDiff(REQUEST_TIME - 12345, REQUEST_TIME, [
'granularity' => 3,
'return_as_object' => TRUE,   ]); }
```

And I use `{{ foo }}` but that does not show "time ago" either. Other things I tried (and which didn't work either):

- `{{ created|date_modify }}`
- `{{ created|time_deff }}`
- `{{ created }}`

Any help/hints about how I can do this?

**Note**: using the same logic as in my previous question ([How can I use 'xx time ago' as date format?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199280/how-can-i-use-xx-time-ago-as-date-format)) and using `MYTHEME_preprocess_comment` instead (as suggested by Neograph734) does not seem to work for comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at what is mentioned on "[Formatting the way the date/time is displayed in Drupal 8](https://knackforge.com/blog/rajamohamed/formatting-way-datetime-displayed-drupal-8)". Here is a quote from it:

> You can change the date format for comment using template_preprocess_comment(). For example, normally in comments the comment created time is displayed like Thu, 12/17/2015 - 23:04. We can change the format to look like 3 weeks 5 Days ago.

And this is the sample code mentioned below it:

```
/**
* Implements hook_preprocess_comment
*/
function THEME_NAME_preprocess_comment(&$variables) {
  // Getting the node creation time stamp from the comment object.
  $date = $variables['comment']->getCreatedTime();
  // Here you can use drupal's format_date() function, or some custom php date formatting.
  $variables['created'] = \Drupal::service('date.formatter')->formatInterval(REQUEST_TIME - $date);
  $variables['submitted'] = t('@username commented !datetime', array('@username' => $variables['author'], '!datetime' => '<span class="comments-ago">' . $variables['created'] . ' ago </span>'));
}
```

I haven't tested this code (yet), but it looks pretty close to what you're asking for ...

Comment: I'm not sure that the 'ago' part will be translated as it comes from the !datetime placeholder.